# unable to show username in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

i have implemented authentication using jwt tokenization and after login I want to display username on the navbar, but it is not showing anything and giving error on console "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" but after refreshing the page it is showing the username and still giving the same error on the console.

Here is my code

NavbarComponent.ts

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../shared/user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { AdminAuthGuard } from '../../guards/admin.auth.guard';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {


  user$: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private adminGuard: AdminAuthGuard) {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe((user) => {
      console.log('fsdf' + user.user.email);
      this.user$ =  user.user;
    });
   }



  onLogoutClick() {
    // console.log('this.user' + this.user$.email);
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

The html code in which i'm printing the username.

```js
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLink="/register">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">Shopping Cart</a>
      </li>
      
      <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a  ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"  aria-expanded="false">{{ user$.username }}</a>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/profile">Profile</a>
          
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders">Manage Orders</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products">Manage Products</a>
          <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="onLogoutClick()">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

The authentication service code.**Focus on getProfile() method**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
// import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
// import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { User } from '../shared/user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  domain = 'http://localhost:3000';
  authToken;
  user;
  options;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/register', user).map(res => res.json());
  }

  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers : new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': this.authToken
      })
    });

  }

  loadToken() {
    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  checkUsername(username) {
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/checkUsername/' + username).map(res => res.json());
  }

  checkEmail(email) {
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/checkEmail/' + email).map(res => res.json());
  }

  login(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/login', user).map(res => res.json());
  }



  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  getProfile() {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/profile', this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }



  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

}
```

This is the http routed API which is fetching the user from mongodb database written in Node.js. Focus on get() for '/profile' method, it's returning an Observable.

```js
const User = require('../models/user'); // Import User Model Schema

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = (router) => {
  /* ==============
     Register Route
  ============== */
  router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    // Check if email was provided
    if (!req.body.email) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'You must provide an e-mail' }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Check if username was provided
      if (!req.body.username) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'You must provide a username' }); // Return error
      } else {
        // Check if password was provided
        if (!req.body.password) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'You must provide a password' }); // Return error
        } else {
          // Create new user object and apply user input
          let user = new User({
            email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
            username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
            password: req.body.password
          });
          // Save user to database
          user.save((err) => {
            // Check if error occured
            if (err) {
              // Check if error is an error indicating duplicate account
              if (err.code === 11000) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username or e-mail already exists' }); // Return error
              } else {
                // Check if error is a validation rror
                if (err.errors) {
                  // Check if validation error is in the email field
                  if (err.errors.email) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.email.message }); // Return error
                  } else {
                    // Check if validation error is in the username field
                    if (err.errors.username) {
                      res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.username.message }); // Return error
                    } else {
                      // Check if validation error is in the password field
                      if (err.errors.password) {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: err.errors.password.message }); // Return error
                      } else {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Return any other error not already covered
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not save user. Error: ', err }); // Return error if not related to validation
                }
              }
            } else {
              res.json({ success: true, message: 'Acount registered!' }); // Return success
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });

  router.get('/checkEmail/:email', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.params.email) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'email not provided'});
    } else {
      User.findOne({ email: req.params.email}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: err});
        } else {
          if (user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'email taken'});
          } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'email available'});
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  router.get('/checkUsername/:username', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.params.username) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'username not provided'});
    } else {
      User.findOne({ username: req.params.username}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: err});
        } else {
          if (user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'username taken'});
          } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'username available'});
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.username) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'No username was provided'});
    } else {
      if (!req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No password was provided'});
      } else {
        User.findOne({ username: req.body.username.toLowerCase() }, (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: err});
          } else {
            if (!user) {
              res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user exist'});
            } else {
              const validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
              if (!validPassword) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'password invalid'});
              } else {
                const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id}, config.secret, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                res.json({ success: true, message: 'Success!', token: token, user: {username: user.username}});
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

// MIDDLEWARE TO INTERCEPT HEADERS
// THIS MIDDLEWARE DECRYPTS THE TOKEN
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // whenever a request coming from angular2 with headers attached it is going to search fot this header
    if (!token) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'No token provided'});
    } else {
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'invalid token' + err});
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  })
// ANY ROUTES COMING AFTER THIS MIDDLEWARE WILL PASS THROUGH THE SAME

// BELOW METHOD TAKES THE DECRYPTED TOKEN FIND THE USER
  router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }).select('username email isAdmin').exec((err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: err});
      } else {
        if (!user) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'user not found'});
        } else {
          res.json({ success: true, user: user });
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return router; // Return router object to main index.js
}
```

Comment: Change it to `user$?.username` to make use of the null safe operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: TypeError: l\_thing0 is undefined in \[{{thing.title}} in AppComponent@4:44\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent)

Comment: any answers....?

Comment: The answer below should resolve it... It may be easier if you create a StackBlitz with your code that reproduces the issue

Comment: is there any other way you could analyse my problem... Right now I'm using visual studio code. It will be a long process to create an entire project on stackBlitz.

Comment: Well the initial analysis makes it seem that the solution below should work. You can drag and drop files into StackBlitz, it shouldn't be that tough. And you don't need to copy the entire project-- just enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user184994 I've pushed my code on github, here is the url:
https://github.com/agamjain14/ShopingCartV1.2/tree/productmanagement

Comment: @user184994 is there any other way you could analyse the problem. May be using anydesk...

Comment: SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: ANY SOLUTION...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **`safe navigation operator`** or *ngIf since you are making a request to your API and getting the data asynchronously. Try as follows,

```
   <a  ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"  aria-expanded="false">{{ user$?.username }}</a>
```

Comment: not working but error on console is gone .
PS: the username is getting displayed after the second refresh

Comment: try using within ngOnInit() instead of constructor

Comment: even after trying ngOninit?

Comment: are you getting the data on console before refresh

Comment: no getting this error when printing it on console
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

Comment: thats strange, because you already have safe navigation operator on html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this happen to you because you're trying to access **user$.username**  when username property doesn't exist. To avoid that error you can use a defined type and then initialize, eg.

```
public $user: UserInterface = {
    username: ''
}
```

or whether you don't want to use defined types, just add an extra validation to html block using ngIf, eg.

```
<a  *ngIf="user$.username" ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"  aria-expanded="false">{{ user$.username }}</a>
```

btw, as a good coding practice, use public method declaration for methods that are shared between code and view, aot build will thanks to you.